# VBA - сравнить две переменные

Tags: vba

В VBA необходимо сравнить две переменные, одна из которых запрашивается через пользовательскую форму, а вторая берется из таблицы ексель. 
В результате получается, что из экселя приходит числовая переменная, а из формы (почему-то) текстовая. 
В результате сравнения всегда получается, что текстовая больше, чем числовая, что есть неправильно.

Как сделать так, чтобы из пользовательской формы приходило числовое значение?

Comment: А скастить в число не вариант?

Comment: @VladD расскажи как это сделать?

Comment: [`val()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Val-Function-e5e1f21b-22f9-41c9-bd0a-fe55b767f603)?

Comment: гугл работает вроде.

Comment: @VladD , можно пример. Я просто в этом VBA чет ниочень. Типо Val(peremennaia)

Comment: @u_mulder было бы просто найти, я бы не стал беспокоить.

Comment: Обычно это называется `приведение типов`

Comment: @anj1817: Ну, у вас есть строка `s`, содержащая число. Чтобы получить это самое число, заводите новую переменную `v` и присваиваете ей значение `Val(s)`. Теперь это число (`v`) можно сравнивать с другими.

Comment: @VladD ответьте на вопрос, предыдущим сообщением и я зачту Вам его как правильный.

Comment: @anj1817: сделал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас есть строка `s`, содержащая число. Чтобы получить это самое число, заводите новую переменную `v` и присваиваете ей значение `Val(s)` ([документация](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Val-Function-e5e1f21b-22f9-41c9-bd0a-fe55b767f603)). Теперь это число (`v`) можно сравнивать с другими.

Answer (score 2):

То, что из формы приходит текст, правильно - все поля на форме текстовые.
И то, что текстовую запись нужно переводить в числовую, тоже правильно.

Но применение оператора *Val* не всегда корректно.

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox Val(1.5)
End Sub
```

Результат работы  - единица, не 1,5 (в VBA разделитель - точка). Происходит это потому, что *Val* считает числом все, что найдено до НЕ ЧИСЛОВОГО знака и в данном примере отрежет дробную часть.

Поэтому во многих случаях правильнее преобразовывать в число типа *Double*:

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox CDbl(1.5)
End Sub
```

И, естественно, переменные должны быть соответствующего типа.

Answer (score 0):

Число из формы нужно проверять на корректность, а только потом преобразовывать. Аналогично и с числом в ячейке. Как вариант можно использовать Replace для игры с точкой и запятой в числе, которое вводится в форме. Ниже приведена функция для проверки на Double

```
  Private Function IsDouble(ByVal value As Variant) As Boolean
     IsDouble = (VarType(value) = vbDouble)
  End Function
```

А вот теперь можно преобразовывать и сравнивать. Ниже пример кода

```
Sub Comparison()

  a = InputBox("Введите число", "ЧИСЛО А") 'Число из бокса, можно с формы...

  If IsDouble(a) = False Then 'Проверка. Является ли число Double
    MsgBox " Число а введено некорректно", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
  End If

  b = Range("A1").value 'Считываем из ячейки А1, это пример

  If IsDouble(b) = False Then 'Проверка. Является ли число Double
    MsgBox " Число b введено некорректно", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
  End If


  If CDble(a) > b Then
    MsgBox " A > B ", vbInformation
  ElseIf a < b Then
    MsgBox " A < B ", vbInformation
  Else
   'Другие варианты уже сам....
  End If

End Sub
```

Вот так правильнее